# Add search toolbar over google map like in native android app

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to implement search toolbar like in native google maps app. How can I make this? May be there is native way to implement this feature?

[image: snapshot from google maps app]

Comment: Use `ToolBar` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should go for use AutoSuggestEditext and give background effect like google have and put left and right image by `Relativelayout`

Here is example for Auto Suggest for place search .

[Auto Place complete](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-places/blob/master/PlaceCompleteFragment/Application/src/main/java/com/example/google/playservices/placecompletefragment/MainActivity.java)

Hope from it you will understand.

Comment: The link seems to be broken, can you please fix it.

Answer (score 14):

You can use `EditText` or `TextWatcher`. I used an `EditText` and a Search button. With this on button click, it search location.

Here is my code on button click :

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String g = searchview.getText().toString();

            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext());
            List<Address> addresses = null;

            try {
                // Getting a maximum of 3 Address that matches the input
                // text
                addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(g, 3);
                if (addresses != null && !addresses.equals(""))
                    search(addresses);

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }

        }
    });
```

and here is search method

```
protected void search(List<Address> addresses) {

    Address address = (Address) addresses.get(0);
    home_long = address.getLongitude();
    home_lat = address.getLatitude();
    latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());

    addressText = String.format(
            "%s, %s",
            address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ? address
                    .getAddressLine(0) : "", address.getCountryName());

    markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    markerOptions.title(addressText);

    map1.clear();
    map1.addMarker(markerOptions);
    map1.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    map1.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
    locationTv.setText("Latitude:" + address.getLatitude() + ", Longitude:"
            + address.getLongitude());


}
```

Edited- for xml code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.google_map.MainActivity" >

 <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/latlongLocation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/searchView1"
    android:background="#ff058fff"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/searchView1"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:hint="Search Location"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:background="@android:color/white" >
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="28dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/searchView1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/searchView1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/searchView1"
    android:background="@drawable/g_search_btn" /></RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Nice answer! It could be enhanced by including some XML to show how you would overlay the EditText, but this is a pretty clear explanation for how you would use it.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to get view Like Search View of Google map. Then you can use anyone of below two awesome library.

1) [Floating Search View](https://github.com/arimorty/floatingsearchview)

Add below dependencie to your gradle file:

```
compile 'com.github.arimorty:floatingsearchview:2.0.3'
```

Example:

```
   <com.arlib.floatingsearchview.FloatingSearchView
            android:id="@+id/floating_search_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:floatingSearch_searchBarMarginLeft="@dimen/search_view_inset"
            app:floatingSearch_searchBarMarginTop="@dimen/search_view_inset"
            app:floatingSearch_searchBarMarginRight="@dimen/search_view_inset"
            app:floatingSearch_searchHint="Search..."
            app:floatingSearch_suggestionsListAnimDuration="250"
            app:floatingSearch_showSearchKey="false"
            app:floatingSearch_leftActionMode="showHamburger"
            app:floatingSearch_menu="@menu/menu_main"
            app:floatingSearch_close_search_on_keyboard_dismiss="true"/>
```

2) [SearchView](https://github.com/lapism/SearchView)

Add below dependencie to your gradle file:

```
compile 'com.lapism:searchview:4.0'
```

Example:

```
<com.lapism.searchview.SearchView
    android:id="@+id/searchView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: hello, could you help me know how to use it with google places?

Comment: Hey, how to get text from these views?

Comment: @MonirZzaman you need to use `setOnQueryChangeListener` to get text from search view in case of `FloatingSearchView`

Answer (score 1):

This might help somebody who want to add search bar along with the Google maps [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/)