# android - Add a Marker to a Fragment Map from Activity

Tags: android, google-maps, fragment

I need to Add a Mark to a Android Google Map (Fragment) from a MainActivity

This is my code;

```
class Map extends android.app.Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_mapa, container,false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        MapFragment fragment = (MapFragment)getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        fragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        LatLng marker = new LatLng(19.33978502, -99.19086277);
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(marker, 15));
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("Marca de Prueba 1").position(marker));
    }
}
```

And i want to add a mark from here:

All this because i want to interact with my map from my main Activity where i have some buttons and EditText

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivityextends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener
{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_side_bar);
    }

    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new Mapa()).commit();
}
```

[Here is how it looks, already has a mark, but insted of calling it from the map activity i need to set it from the MainActivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lylpH.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to define a public method in the Fragment that can be called from the Activity:

```
class Mapa extends android.app.Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback

    GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_mapa, container,false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        MapFragment fragment = (MapFragment)getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        fragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
    }

    //Added public method to be called from the Activity
    public void placeMarker(String title, double lat, double lon) {
      if (mMap != null) {
        LatLng marker = new LatLng(lat, lon);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(marker, 15));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title(title).position(marker));
      }
    }
}
```

Then, in the Activity, keep a reference to the Fragment so that you can call the `placeMarker()` method:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

  private Mapa mMapFragment;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_side_bar);
      }

      mMapFragment = new Mapa();
      FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
      fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, mMapFragment).commit();
  }

  private void placeMarkerInMap(String title, double lat, double lon) {
    if (mMapFragment != null) {
       mMapFragment.placeMarker(title, lat, lon); 
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can call the `placeMarkerInMap()` method in your Activity when the user fills out the EditText and clicks the button.

Note that if you try to call this method before the `onMapReady()` callback executes, there will not be a valid GoogleMap reference to use to place the Marker.
If you need to place a Marker on initial launch from the Activity, you'll need to use arguments in the FragmentTransaction.  [See here for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17436298/how-to-pass-a-variable-from-activity-to-fragment-and-pass-it-back).

Comment: Thank you!

I did what you say but when i call the placeMarker method on the main acticity it says that cannot resolve. :S any ideas?

Comment: My Fragment is called Mapa*

Comment: @JosCarrillo I see what the problem is.  I just updated the answer. The declaration should actually be `private Mapa mMapFragment;`, change that and it will work.

Comment: Thanks! Now is Workin, i have to change the placeMarker method static and the Google map mMap to static too. 
Very thankful!!

Comment: @JosCarrillo I would not recommend making it static.... You should be able to make it work without making it static!

Comment: I tried, but it says 'Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context'.

Comment: can you please helpe me, telling me where i have to put the getLastLocation() method to get the current location of a client... is it on the Main Activity or the Map Fragment. 

Thank you

Comment: @JosCarrillo For getting the current location in a Google Map in a Fragment, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41754169/4409409