# How to add searchbar for map of this code

Tags: android-studio

I'm new to AndroidStudio.I'm using corrected example to add google map using fragment for my project [Show Current Location inside Google Map Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41753706/show-current-location-inside-google-map-fragment-) first Answer.So now i'm conflict with adding search bar for this.Can anyone guide me to add searchbar for my project.Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could try following the steps from [here](https://www.viralandroid.com/2016/04/google-maps-android-api-adding-search-bar-part-3.html).

For adding a search-bar to the Google maps android API.

Comment: I tried it, I used fragment to get mapactivity to navigationdrawer now if i edit my fragment layout it not show that search bar and also that function onmapsearch doesn't  use.

Comment: Does your application have a navbar, if so why not put the search bar there?

Comment: I need to search some destinations on the map.And also need to introduce some options for app