# how to insert navigation drawer and button inside AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android

Basically I want to insert navigation drawer and button inside AutoCompleteTextView like search text in google map.

How do I do that ?

[image: Google map pic]

thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to define your layout (the searchbox), which will have an `ImageView`. Then you can add an `OnClickListener()` to open the `NavigationDrawer`.

You could combine it with something like this:

[Add search toolbar over google map like in native android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31136527/add-search-toolbar-over-google-map-like-in-native-android-app)

Comment: If it answered your question, mark it as answer please.